# Dependency on the 5 parts of Mitzvat Hakhel

Tags: mitzvah, vayelech, hakhel

According to Rambam ([CHagigah 3](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Mishneh_Torah%2C_Festival_Offering.3.1?lang=he&with=all&lang2=he)), the Mitzva of Hakhel has five parts:

1. the people: men, women and children, that come to hear the reading by
2. a king that reads the portion of
3. the Torah Scroll
4. in the Temple
5. on Motzey Shvi'is (7th-year cycle)

Rambam (as usual) describes an ideal situation where all five exist. What I couldn't understand is: **Could the Mitzvah be fulfilled in the absence of some of them?**:

1. Could a Mitzva be fulfilled if only a small group comes to the occasion, say, only 50 people?
2. Was the Mitzvah performed in times of Yehoshuah or other prophets and Judges (whether they were or weren't a king)?
3. Does it have to be a full Kosher scroll, or just the portions he reads (similar to Parashat Sotah)?
4. Or in times of king Saul or David when there was no Temple?
5. Can it be only performed when the cycle is counted and not spontaneously by King's order?

---

<sub>Because it's a single topic I decided to post it as one question, but if you see the need to separate, please comment.</sub>